# Simple encryption technique for MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

How do I encrypt a user password in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)?

Please explain in a way a beginner can understand. I already have this sample code:

```
$password = "john856";
$encrypt_password = md5($password);

echo $encrypt_password;
```

How do I incorporate it in my current code, which does not do any encryption?

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

    mysql_select_db("koro", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO users
            (LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, UNAME, PW)
          VALUES
            ('$_POST[Lneym]', '$_POST[Fneym]', '$_POST[Mneym]', '$_POST[Uneym]', '$_POST[Pass]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }

    echo "<script>alert('User added! You can now use the system.')</script>";

    mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: If you want people to do your work, the least you could do is format the code nicely!

Comment: For more info on formatting your post, see the markdown reference page: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You have serious mySQL injection issues in that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with a more important point:

You must *never* pass through $_POST variables directly into the query. This makes you extremely vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Using_Parameterized_Statements).

You should at the very least least run [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://de.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on every form value you insert:

```
$Lneym = $_POST["Lneym"];
$Lneym_halfway_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($Lneym);

....

$sql="INSERT INTO users 
          (LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, UNAME, PW)
        VALUES 
          ('$Lneym_halfway_safe',
```

You can then also incorporate the md5() straight away:

```
$PW = md5($_POST["PW"]);  // no escape_string() needed here, 
                          // the md5 checksum is safe
```

and then insert `'$PW'` for the password field.

The best thing would be using a database class like [PDO](https://www.php.net/PDO). Its parametrized queries feature automatically helps prevent SQL injections. Maybe [**this tutorial**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) helps you.

Seeing as you are not even able to add `md5()` to your code (no personal criticism, we all started there once) I strongly recommend you read up on programming basics. Copy-pasting crucial security features for a web platform is horribly dangerous and is likely to end in tears.

Comment: -1: good advice, but nothing to do with answering the actual question.

Comment: Now it is. I didn't refresh before posting the comment, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You are practically there. Run your code:

```
$password=$_POST["pass"];
$encrypt_password=md5($password);
```

and then insert $encrypt_password into the password field in the database:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users 
          (LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, UNAME, PW)
        VALUES 
          ('$_POST[Lneym]', '$_POST[Fneym]', '$_POST[Mneym]', '$_POST[Uneym]', '$encrypt_password')";
```

I should add, however, that MD5 is a hash algorithm which is a one-way process which generates a unique string on each input ("collisions aside"). You will not be able to recover the user's password, just so you know. This is however a good thing and you can still check logins - just compare md5 values.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [MySQL's encryption functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, escape all variables:

```
$encrypt_password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST["pass"]));
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[Lneym]);
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[Fneym]);
$midname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[Mneym]);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[Uneym]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users
          (LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, UNAME, PW)
          VALUES
          ('$lastname', '$fistname', '$middlename', '$username', '$encrypt_password')";
```

Then for login:

```
$encrypt_password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST["pass"]))
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[Uneym]);
$sql = "SELECT LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, UNAME
        WHERE UNAME = '$username'
        AND PW = '$encrypt_password'";
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know using [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) is a better (more secure) way than [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or even [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) to hash your passwords.

A while ago I used this page tutorial for my [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system), and it works really fine.

```
http://hungred.com/useful-information/php-better-hashing-password/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Hungredcom+%28Hungred.com%29
```

It's pretty coded and is secure enough to use, because it's trying to combine a private function for securing passwords.